# Javascript recursion on mouseOver not working?

Tags: javascript

The following code is supposed to gently vary the color of a tab, which i pass into the function. However, the gradient only increases every new time that i enter the tab, instead of increasing the one time i put the mouse over...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        hex=255;
    function fadetext(element){ 

    if(hex>0) {
        hex-=11;
        element.style.backgroundColor="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
        setTimeout("fadetext(element)",50); 
    }
    else
        hex=255;
    }
</script>


    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
         <li><a href="tab-frame-css.html" class="selected" target="mainFrame"  onMouseOver = "fadetext(this)" onclick="loadit(this)">Personal details</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: shouldn't be onmouseover instead of onMouseOver ?

Comment: @Matias: HTML (unlike XML) is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

For the timeout, element is undefined when using it as text. You should use an anoymous function:

```
var elem=element;//I find that this is needed in some browsers
setTimeout(function(){fadetext(elem);},50);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you are missing a closing bracket `}` at the end of `fadetext`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the curly brace to end the function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        hex=255;
    function fadetext(element){ 

    if(hex>0) {
        hex-=11;
        element.style.backgroundColor="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
        setTimeout("fadetext(element)",50); 
    }
    else
        hex=255;
    }
} // You're missing this one here
</script>
```

Comment: I put the bracket in the wrong place, its not for the else, but for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `setTimeout()` call with:

```
setTimeout(function(){fadetext(element);},50);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more **robust** approach, with **smooth** animation. Usage: fadeText("elementid", 1000);
Also, you can **reuse** this  **for any kind of animation**. Just change the values between you interpolate, and the style setting part.

```
function interpolate( start, end, pos ) {
  return start + ( pos * (end - start) );
}

function fadeText( dom, interval, delay ) {

      interval = interval || 1000;
      delay    = delay    || 10;

  var start    = Number(new Date());

  if ( typeof dom === "string" ) {
    dom = document.getElementById( dom );
  }

  function step() {

    var now     = Number(new Date()),
        elapsed = now - start,
        pos     = elapsed / interval,
        value   = ~~interpolate( 255, 0, pos );

    dom.style.backgroundColor =
    "rgb("+value+","+value+","+value+")";

    if ( elapsed < interval )
      setTimeout( step, delay );
  }

  setTimeout( step, delay );
}
```